# Data is to be returned from another method, than the one, a parallel thread returns it to

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, httpconnection

I have a class that extends AsyncTask.

In the doInBackground() method, I connect to a server and get data.

The said class has a method get() that returns this data to the user.

So I call execute() method in this class and soon after, return a member variable "response".

But null is being returned because, the connection is not made yet.

So, I set the variable "response" in onPostExecute() and want to return to the main thread from here.

How will I do this without using a loop like this:

```
while(! gotResponse) continue;
```

My pseudo code:

```
//Main thread
class blah {
   .... onCreate(..) {
      ConHelper ch = new ConHelper();
      String data = ch.get();
   }
}
class ConHelper extends AsyncTask<...>{
   private String response;
   private boolean gotResponse;

   ... get() {
      this.execute(...);
      while(! this.gotResponse) continue;
      return this.response;
   }
   ... doInBackground(..) {
      // connect and get data.
   }
   ... on postExecute(...) {
      //set response and gotResponse from obtained data.
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of `AsyncTask` is that the *task itself* initiates whatever needs to be done once the results are available. A method like `get()` cannot be implemented. Certainly do not try waiting on the main (UI) thread until the results are available. (By the way, `AsyncTask` already defines a `get()` method to retrieve the results. If the results are not available, it will block until they are. Do not call it from the UI thread.)

The way to do this is to have `onPostExecute()` initiate whatever needs to be done once the results are available. This method is called on the UI thread after all the time-consuming work of `doInBackground()` has finished.

Write your UI logic (`onCreate()`, etc.) so that it does not have to wait on the results, and so that it works when results are not yet available. (So, for instance, you could display a blank field or a "please wait" message where you would like to display `data`. Or you could pop up a "working" alert dialog and remove it from within `onPostExecute()`.)

Comment: So are you saying that the blah class should extend AsyncTask? But this is not possible because it already extends Activity.

Comment: I just read about the get method in AsyncTask. I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @Brahadeesh - I'm saying that your `ConHelper` class should initiate whatever work needs to be done once the results are available. Think of it this way: you wouldn't write your code to "wait" for the user to touch the screen. You would write an `OnClickListener` or something to react when the event happened. Think of `onPostExecute()` as an event handler for when the results are available. Don't call `get()` from your main thread; that will force the UI to wait for the results. The system will generate an "Application Not Responding" error if the communication takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a way to do it in the Android framework.  If you are worried about spinning then you could do something like:

```
final Object lock = new Object();

// wait until the value has been set
synchronized (lock) {
    // we do a while loop to protect against interrupts and race conditions
    while(response == null) {
        try {
            lock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you are ready to set the response you'd do a:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    response = ...;
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. But isnt it similar to the method I used?

Comment: Sure but it doesn't spin.  As I said, if you are worried about it spinning then this will help.  If you are looking for an Android architecture solution then maybe @Ted's answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

[Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp)'s answer is what you are looking for. I'm adding this answer to post some code. As Ted implied, your Activity should just go about it's business while the `AsyncTask` does it's work.

When `ConHelper` is done, it can access the Activity via `onPostExecute`, which runs **on the main thread**.

You certainly don't want to call `get` on from `onCreate` because the `while` loop in `get` is just going to cause the main thread to block, defeating the entire reason for creating the `ConHelper` in the first place.

The key is that you want to structure your `Activity` so that it can run without access to any data obtained in `ConHelper`. If you cannot continue without the variable `data` from your `onCreate` example, then moving work off the main thread is not going to help you.

So let's take a hypothetical where you want to do some lengthy call that returns a `String` which you would like to display in a `TextView`. Here's one way to do it:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
   protected TextView myTextView;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main); // or whatever layout you have
      myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview); //or whatever widgets/ids you use
      ConHelper ch = new ConHelper();
      ch.execute();
   }

   class ConHelper extends AsyncTask<..., Void, String>{

      protected String doInBackground(..) {
        // connect and get data.
        return <some lengthy method call that returns a String>;
      }
      protected void onPostExecute(String resultFromDoInBackground) {
        myTextView.setText(resultFromDoInBackground);
      }
   }
}
```